# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_\epsilon(x)g(x)dx=g(0)$ (Dirac delta function))

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, analysis, exponential-function

I'm currently studying the Dirac delta function using a textbook which unfortunately provides only partial solutions to its explanations. Why does $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_\epsilon(x)g(x)dx=g(0)$ if $ f_\epsilon=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}}$? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik What makes you think so?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought of something else.

Comment: What is $g$ here? The answer depends on the type of $g$ you want to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a change of variable:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \, e^{-|x|/\epsilon} g(x) \, dx
= \{ y = x/\epsilon \}
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|y|} \, g(\epsilon y) \, dy \\
\to \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|y|} \, g(0) \, dy
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|y|} \, dy \right) \, g(0)
= g(0)
$$
The [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) has been used when taking the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Set $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$, so $\frac{1}{\epsilon} f(x/\epsilon) =f_\epsilon$ and  $||f||_{L^1} = 1$ for $\epsilon\in (0,1]$, so for any test functions $g\in C_c^\infty$ you have
$$\int\frac{1}{\epsilon} f(x/\epsilon)g(x)dx = \int f(x)g(\epsilon x)dx$$
$$=\int f(x)[g(0) + g'(0)\epsilon x + ...]dx$$
$$ =g(0)\int f(x)dx + \int_{}f(x)[\epsilon xg'(0) + \frac{g''(0)(x\epsilon)^2}{2}+ ...]dx$$
The expansion is valid by the support and regularity assumption and $f\in \mathcal{S}$. So you have the limit 
$$\int\frac{1}{\epsilon} f(x/\epsilon)g(x)dx \rightarrow g(0)\int f(x)dx = g(0)$$
hence $f_\epsilon \rightarrow \delta$ in the distributional sense