# Dirac delta distribution

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

when I want to show that limit of the following function $$f_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}}~,$$ namely, $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f_\epsilon(x)$$ is a presentation of $\delta$-distribution. And for that, I have to show that for each test function $g$ we have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f_\epsilon(x)g(x)=g(0)$$
We can assume to interchange integration and limits.
How do I do that? Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Can you mimic the approach used in [another representation of Dirac $\delta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025023/11619)?

Comment: not really, I´m really stumped in this case :(

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3192258/168433

Comment: Gosh, thanks guys. This task seems to occupy a lot of us :)

Comment: $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}f_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}}$$
if we let $a=\frac1\epsilon$ and take the limit as $0^+$ then we can say that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}}=\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac a2e^{-a|x|}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{a}{e^{a|x|}}$$
now use L'Hopital and if we assume $|x|>0$ which is always true for $x\in R$. We can evaluate the limit as $0$. As for the second bit I think people have provided links with the answer

Answer (score 0):

This means do the integral of $f_{\epsilon}(x)g(x)$ for a given $g()$, then take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of the answer that you get.

Note: to do the integral, you should split up into $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ to tackle the modulus.